# Mapping "LinkedList" with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have linked list kind of situation. My DTO looks like this -

```
public class DTOItem
{
    public string ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? UniqueId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Payload
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //How do I map this guy? It is list of same type.
    public List<DTOItem> RelatedItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

How do I map this guy using AutoMapper? I am able to map other members of the class. Data is mapped from another class' collection object that has a different set of member not identical to this class.

```
public List<DTOItem> RelatedItems
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here is the code - 
Raphael, here is the code:

The Source Objects:

```
public class ResultsSet
{
    public int? ResultId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int UID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //Returns large XML string
    public string ResultBlob
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelatedItems[] RelatedSet
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RelatedItems
{
    public int Item_ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Relationship_ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

To map here is the code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ResultSet, DTOItem>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ResultID.GetValueOrDefault(0)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UniqueId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UID))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Payload, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ResultBlob));

            /*
                How do I map RelatedSet to RelatedItems here?
            */

Mapper.Map(result, returnResult);
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Could you give the "source" class(es) and what you tried (mapping) ?

Comment: Hi Raphael, I had added the source classes.

Comment: This is not a linked list... are there any cyclic references in this data?

Comment: Yes, you're correct this is not a linked list. It is more like a tree. No, there won't be any cyclic reference. RelatedSet can have zero or many in the collection. And, items in the RelatedSet collection will not have anymore child DTOItem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use AutoMapper for this. 
For non-cyclic, relatively flat data, this should do:

```
static Func<RelatedItems, DTOItem> MapRelated(IEnumerable<ResultsSet> all) {
    var map = MapResultSet(all);
    return relatedItem => map(all.First(x => x.UID == relatedItem.Item_ID));
}

static Func<ResultsSet, DTOItem> MapResultSet(IEnumerable<ResultsSet> all) {
    return s => 
        new DTOItem {
            ID = s.ResultId.GetOrElse(0).ToString(),
            UniqueId = s.UID,
            Payload = s.ResultBlob,
            RelatedItems = (s.RelatedSet ?? new RelatedItems[0]).Select(MapRelated(all)).ToList()
        };
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var data = new[] { 
    new ResultsSet {
        UID = 1,
        RelatedSet = new[] {
            new RelatedItems { Item_ID = 2 },
            new RelatedItems { Item_ID = 3 },
        },
    },
    new ResultsSet {
        UID = 2,
    },
    new ResultsSet {
        UID = 3,
    },
};
var items = data.Select(MapResultSet(data)).ToList();
Debug.Assert(items.Count == 3);
Debug.Assert(items[0].UniqueId == 1);
Debug.Assert(items[1].UniqueId == 2);
Debug.Assert(items[2].UniqueId == 3);
Debug.Assert(items[0].RelatedItems.Count == 2);
Debug.Assert(items[0].RelatedItems[0].UniqueId == items[1].UniqueId);
Debug.Assert(items[0].RelatedItems[1].UniqueId == items[2].UniqueId);
```

I assumed Item_ID is the 'key' to UID, otherwise simply adjust `MapRelated`.

Generally speaking, I think AutoMapper is only useful if you have to map untyped data into typed data, and even in that case I'd think really hard before using it. Otherwise, some LINQ code is simpler and more type safe.

Comment: There is another class that extends this class which has 30+ members that needs values to be copied to. And, in this case there are mappings between List<string> and string[] etc. How would you suggest this to be done?

Comment: @user1244179 : 1. you didn't specify that in your question, so it should be a new question. 2. you could just write the code, it's trivial. If you mean you need to choose between writing 30 lines of code and breaking the type system, I'll pick the 30 lines of code. If there are common transformations in your domain you can abstract that to (possibly higher-order) functions. 3. having to map a lot of classes to similar ones is a code smell, you might want to revise why you need to do that...